# Reactjs: Checkbox state is update, then reverted when callback function terminates

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox

I'm pretty new to react and I ran into a weird issue today. I have a function called handleCheckBoxClick()

```
handleCheckboxClick : function (e) {
    this.setState({isChecked : e.target.checked},
        function () {
            if (this.state.isChecked) {
                this.props.addToTransactionSubmissions(
                    this.props.submissionGuid, 
                    this.props.paymentInfo
                );
            } else {
                this.props.removeFromTransactionSubmissions(
                    this.props.submissionGuid
                );
            }
        }
    );
}
```

This particular function calls a function passed down through a parent called addTo/removeFromTransactionSubmission. The code for both is as follows:

```
addToTransactionSubmissions : function (guid, paymentInfo) {
    if (Object.keys(this.state.transactionSubmissions).length === 0) {
        this.setState({submissionType : paymentInfo.status_description.toLowerCase()},
            function () {
                console.log('it set the state though');
                console.log(this.state.transactionSubmissions);
                this.toggleButtons(this.state.submissionType);
            }
        );
    }
    var newTansactionSubmissions = update(this.state.transactionSubmissions,
        {
            $merge : {[guid] : paymentInfo}
        });
    this.setState({transactionSubmissions : newTansactionSubmissions},
        function () {
            console.log('state is now', this.state.transactionSubmissions);
        }
     );
},
removeFromTransactionSubmissions : function (guid) {
    if (Object.keys(this.state.transactionSubmissions).length === 0) {
        this.setState({submissionType : undefined},
            function () {
                this.toggleButtons(this.state.submissionType);
            }
        );
    }
    var newTransactionSubmission = update(this.state.transactionSubmissions,
        {
            [guid] : {$apply: function (x) {return undefined}}
        });
    this.setState({transactionSubmissions : newTransactionSubmission},
        function () {
            console.log('here in remove Transaction');
        });
}
```

The problem I run into is that when addTo/removeFromTransactionSubmissions is called, the checkbox does not changes states, even though the state is changed before addTo/removeFromTransactionSubmissions is called. Through further debugging using Firebug, I discovered that 1) the functions are all being called properly, 2) if I do not set state in addTo/removeFromTransactionSubmissions everything runs without a hitch, and 3) the checkbox becomes unchecked after handleCheckboxClick completely finishes.

I suspect that for whatever reason, the state is being lost when Reactjs is trying to update the DOM. However, I do not know why this is the case and don't know how to further debug. And for clarification, the checkbox is in the child component whereas the transactionSubmissions state is in a parent, and on the click of a checkbox, transactionSubmissions is modified (Child Action modifies Parent state). If this is the wrong way to go about the problem, please tell me.

Basically what I want to do is every time I click/unclick a box, it removes the corresponding object to/from a map of ids to the object. Am I doing something incorrectly?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use another aproach.

```
handleCheckboxClick : function (e) {
    this.setState({isChecked : e.target.checked})
}
```

Add a method componentWillUpdate(https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentwillupdate) or componentDidUpdate(https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentdidupdate) and handle there the changes that must occur after state change

```
componentWillUpdate()
{
           if (this.state.isChecked) 
           {
               this.props.addToTransactionSubmissions(
               this.props.submissionGuid, 
               this.props.paymentInfo);
          } else {
          this.props.removeFromTransactionSubmissions(this.props.submissionGuid);
          }
}
```

Also you should not call setState sequencially, it can throw some errors by trying to mutate a component while it was updating.

Every time your code calls setState, react goes trought all the dom, check what has changed and render the changes again, saving processing. Ref:https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'll be trying it out. Could you clarify as to why I shouldn't call setState sequentially? The two setStates are changing two different things in the state so from my understanding, they shouldn't be overwriting each other. And as a further clarification, is it wrong to use this.state.[state_variable] = value in all cases? I don't actually want a rerendering when I change transactionSubmissions.

Comment: Hi @ChangYangJiao. As far as I understand by react docs when you call setState react run throught all the dom, checks the elements that have chaned and renders it. So if you call setState 2 times in a row, react will pass throught the same method doing the same checks, but in the second time it is passing, it may find the DOM updating due the first setState you called, then it may conflict and throw the error DOM changed during component update.

Comment: As this.state.[state_variable] = value as I understand is not correct according to react principles. This is from react docs: NEVER mutate this.state directly, as calling setState() afterwards may replace the mutation you made. Treat this.state as if it were immutable.
setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this method can potentially return the existing value. There is no guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to setState and calls may be batched for performance gains

Comment: Continue: setState() will always trigger a re-render unless conditional rendering logic is implemented in shouldComponentUpdate(). If mutable objects are being used and the logic cannot be implemented in shouldComponentUpdate(), calling setState() only when the new state differs from the previous state will avoid unnecessary re-renders.